# How to Redirect tenant to subdomain home page after user can login in public schema

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-tenants

I have to redirect to home page without login in subdomain after login in public tenant
That means suppose -

public domain is : **logic.com**

subdomain is : **tenant1.logic.com**
I have tried to login to the public domain (logic.com/login) so now I have to redirect to the home page of the subdomain(tenant1.logic.com/home)
Without subdomain login

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'users/login-user.html', {'form': AuthenticationForm()})
    else:
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is None:
            return render(request, 'users/login-user.html', {'form': AuthenticationForm(), 'error': 'Username and '
                                                                                                    'password did not '
                                                                                                    'match'})
        else:
            client = Client.objects.filter(owner=user).first()
            with schema_context(client.schema_name):
                login(request, client.owner)
                host = request.META.get('HTTP_HOST', '')
                scheme_url = request.is_secure() and "https" or "http"
                url = f"{scheme_url}://{client.slug}.{host}"
                return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

What can I do if anyone has know about this?

Thanks in advance

Also I have added install app from setting
[image]

I am getting this error :
**django.contrib.sessions.exceptions.SessionInterrupted: The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example.**

Comment: you are using the same user db for each tenants ?

Comment: @LucasGrugru, Yes I have used tenant_users for user permissions in shared_app and tenat_app

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=".logic.com"
```

in your settings.py for allowing all subdomains for the session.
More informations in django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN

Edit: i did not see your edit, so you have already set the settings opt and it does not work. Tenant_user seems to use the default django backend so it would be work with the settings.
Have you replaced the backend ?

Comment: Lucas Grugru, I have already added in setting file

Comment: Can you check if you have a cookie named **sessionid** in your browser after login ?

Comment: I have only one cookie, it is csrf token

Comment: You have the error you had in first message once or many times ? For once, it is not a problem. Probably on testing you have two tabs opened in same time

Comment: I have got error many times

Comment: You have to check if you enter in the django login function

Comment: Please show more informations: logs console, the views where you arrived in your subdomain redirect url. 
If you have the errors many times, maybe in your process you call login and logout in the same url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248244/discussion-between-coder-and-lucas-grugru).